# How does the Ad Hoc mode work on the PS vita?

Tags: ps-vita

Can someone explain how Ad Hoc mode works to me step by step? My main question is whether you have to have internet or not.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need Internet to play Ad Hoc mode as long as the game you are playing supports it. Here is [a comprehensive list of games supporting the mode](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hr9WKid7Ob9rPxjFu1B6C48FkRP0sttaESVtgOVPGW0/edit#gid=0).

Just leave the "Ad Hoc Mode Channel" set to Automatic and the Vita will take care of the rest if the other players are nearby.